# Why Set Theory as Foundation?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, motivation

Set Theory, particularly ZFC, is the most widely accepted foundation for mathematics.

Why is that? **Why is Set Theory (and, *in particular*, ZFC) the (in some sense) "best" foundation we can come up with?**

There doesn't seem to be any definite detailed answer to this question on the web or on this site.

Comment: There can't be any technical answer here, because this is not a technical question.  ZFC is a relatively small set of axioms that suffice to prove most of what most mathematicians are interested in, so it's been adopted widely.  That doesn't mean it's the "best" in any technical sense.

Comment: "best" is not the correct term; it is (up to now) the most used.

Comment: It's not. Set theory as a foundation is in many ways unwieldy and, to a great extent, the inner workings of the theory don't reflect how we do math in practice

Comment: It emerged in te first half of the 20th Century between "competing theories" for its capability of offering an *unifying language* able to define every known mathematical concept.

Comment: It is useful [The Early Development of Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-early/).

Comment: @leibnewtz I can't find it now, but I remember once reading a paper arguing that it would be better to take functions as foundational instead of sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are other foundational proposals, but set theory has two general advantages:

**It works.** Virtually all of everyday mathematics can be formalized in set theory, so we're pretty sure it contains the foundational uncertainty we will ever need to deal with.

**It is reasonably close to how everyday mathematics is already done.** Speaking of sets is ubiquitous in algebra, analysis, topology -- not because it has been decided that sets are foundational, but because sets *naturally* arise when expressing the things we're interested in there. For example, in group theory we want to talk about subgroups, and defining what a subgroup is naturally leads to an underlying concept of subset.

There are other kinds of things that arise naturally in ordinary mathematics -- numbers, tuples, relations, sequences, functions, etc. -- but most of these can be *represented with* sets in ways that feel relatively straightforwards. Numbers are probably the "least setlike" of the usual kinds of things used in ordinary mathematics, and the usual representations of numbers as sets is not particularly intuitive. But in the big picture that's not really a showstopper, and similar contortions would be needed elsewhere when one uses other foundations.

"Reasonably close to ordinary mathematics" has particular significance not so much for those working directly with foundational problems, as because because those working in *ordinary* mathematics can then feel reasonably comfortable with imagining they're working on top of set theory as a foundation. Since people working outside foundations are also most of those who teach the formalism in a typical undergraduate curriculum (because *most professors of mathematics* work outside foundations), this gives set theory a definite advantage in the battle for mindshare.

**Among set theories**, ZFC has the main benefit of being *simple to explain*. There is only one kind of thing: The set. The basic operations are conceptually simple. In particular the *restrictions* you work under to avoid the paradoxes are fairly easy to adhere to -- most of the way you can get by with Separation, which is much easier for non-specialists to understand and remember than, say, the "stratified" comprehension axiom of NF.

Among **other foundations**, the established proposals that come closer to set theory in matching how ordinary mathematics is done would be various kinds of *category theory*. To me -- and apparently to many others -- they feel somewhat more remote from how you think about ordinary mathematical reasoning than a set-theoretic foundation does. Especially because category theory considers talking about individual "things" to be something to be avoided, it seems to be harder to make a connection between the theoretical framework and actual calculations on concrete examples. But whether this feeling is inherent in the approach or just an effect of having more experience with set theory is very much a matter of debate.

Some **up-and-coming** ideas are modern *type theories*, generally building on a category-theoretic substratum, but with a computational slant that doesn't discourage thinking about individual elements the way classical category theory does. They might end up providing the best of multiple worlds once the technical kinks get evened out. Apart from the considerable inertia of ZFC, their main problem is that they don't have much parsimony of primitive notions. They don't work very well as neat packages of "all the foundational uncertainty we need to worry about".

Some **also-rans**: Foundations based on *integer arithmetic* as their primitive concept, such as various systems for *second-order arithmetic*, can express *large parts* of ordinary mathematics. But even though they *can* represent, say, reasoning about differential equations, the contortions that one needs to go through are complex and not intuitive at all. And these systems still cannot represent *everything* one wants to be able to do in ordinary mathematics. They are mostly studied for specialist purposes, e.g. in *reverse mathematics* because it is easier to construct interestingly *restricted* versions of second-order arithmetic than it is for set or category theory.

Comment: I agree with you about the simplicity of set theoretic foundation compared to other foundations. With just a single $\in$ relation and a few axioms we can do so much. But saying that category theory is not how many people think about mathematics is probably not true. The usual argument goes that category theory lets you focus on structure: we don't care *what* is an integer, we just care about the structure of the integers themselves (and their relations with other structures), whereas in set theory an integer is this or that, but not both.

Comment: (Of course, anyone who has seriously tried to understand set theoretic foundations should know, set theory also doesn't care what is an integer, and has the tools to prove that it doesn't care, namely Replacement axioms, but using these tools requires more experience with set theory, so people prefer to just make the claims that the elements "matter" somehow.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think there is a difference in degree between saying "don't worry about what $5$ _is_; here is how it _behaves_" (as a set-theoretic foundation does) and "don't even dare to think about $5$ at all, that is evil. Think about $\mathbb Z$ and maps between $\mathbb Z$ and other things instead", as category theory does. Category theory does, begrudgingly, let me speak of a constant function $x\mapsto 5$ and lets me think about $f(5)$ by composing that constant function with $f$, but it definitely wants me to feel filthy for doing so.

Comment: Set theory to me feels like it departs in many ways from how mathematicians think about mathematical objects. For example I doubt many geometers think about a manifold as a tuple containing a collection of points, certain subsets of these collections, etc. On the other hand category theory allows us to not worry about how such objects are constructed. Instead you can start to think about the relationships between objects (e.g smooth functions), which in practice is what we do every day

Comment: On the other hand set theory as a foundational system can do everything category theory can do and more. For that reason I think set theory is the best foundation we have at the moment, but it's certainly far from the best we can come up with

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an HSM question, but I'll try to answer partly historically and partly in terms of theory.

Nineteenth-century paradoxes led to set theories such as ZFC. One advantage it has over some other theories is a lack of urelements, so we don't need a set predicate constantly cluttering axioms and theorems. The downside of that is you can't talk about anything that cannot be construed as a set. But it was quickly realised you can easily represent just about any "traditional" mathematical structure of interest through its isomorphism to a certain set's contents, provided we define operations on them the right way (e.g. if you think of finite ordinals as representing non-zero negative integers, it's not too hard to decide how we'll define arithmetic on them).

Around this time, the people interested in foundational questions were generally involved in set theory, to a greater or less extent or a more or less tangential one. For example, Russell's paradox comes from the more philosophically inclined of the authors of Principia Mathematica. Mathematicians had just had a few decades of a castle-building whirlwind, where complex numbers had lost their controversy and even more esoteric structures had entered the field. Were quaternions OK? What about groups? The realisation was that we should really ask what things do, not what they are, if only because there will be many structures that do the same thing.

So in short, what happened was this: people worried about which objects were legal noticed sets had been used uncritically, including in some cases sets of sets; set theory had to be given a bit of rigour just to avoid easily formulated paradoxes; but the seemingly robust ZFC, despite lacking urelements, could model everything before it, so anyone who believed ZFC was consistent was also assured "normal" maths is as well.